# using sed to search for first 3 and last 3 occurrences of all the files

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

What is the best way to search for the top 3 and bottom 3 occurrences of a string in all the files of a directory and output the result to a file?

I am currently doing it with 2 commands. But is there a better way?

```
grep string path-to-file | head -3 > out.log
grep string path-to-file | tail -3 >> out.log
```

Comment: When you say `in all the files` - are you searching for a string in multiple files? If do you want the top 3 and bottom 3 matching lines of each file output or of all files together? What should the output look like if there aren't 6 output lines? Please [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input and expected output and make sure you cover the edge cases, not just the simple sunny day case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done in a single awk call, e.g:

```
awk -v n=3 '
FNR == 1 && NR != 1 {
    i = ((c - n) >= n ? c - n : n) + 1 
    for (; i <= c; i++)
        print m[i]   
    c = 0 
    delete m
}
/pattern to match/ {
    c++
    if (c <= n)
        print
    else {
        delete m[c - n]
        m[c] = $0
    }
}
END {
    i = ((c - n) >= n ? c - n : n) + 1 
    for (; i <= c; i++)
        print m[i]
}' *
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Never used those arguments with awk before.

Comment: @CharanTeja are you sure this produces the output you expect when there are less than 6 lines of input to awk?

Comment: @Ed Ugh, I don't even know what I was thinking while posting this. It hurts my eyes

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested:

```
see -n '
    /PATTERN/!{$be;d};
    1h;1!H;
    :e;
    ${g;s,^\([\n]\+\n[\n]\+\n[\n]\+\n\).*\([\n]\+\n[\n]\+\n[\n]\+\),\1\2,;p}
'
```

The idea is:

1. to ignore all the lines which don't contain the PATTERN pattern.
2. to save all the lines that contain PATTERN in the hold space
3. to read the hold space at the end and store the first 3 lines in the first group and the last 3 lines in the second group

I don't have access to a computer now, I will check it later and fix it if necessary

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/PATTERN/H;$!d;x;s/^((\n[^\n]*){3}).*((\n[^\n]*){3})$/\1\3/;s/.//p' file
```

Gather up lines that contain `PATTERN` in the hold space and at the end of the file, swap to the hold space, remove any lines between the first and last three lines ,remove the introduced newline and print if successful.